# Good way to show PDF on page from Storage

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I'm trying to stream PDF files so it's visible on the necessary page, but what I've tried up to now doesn't work at all. I'm trying BarryVdh/domPDF right now, but keep getting "This file extension is forbidden" and I don't know how to fix it.

```
public function paycheck($id)
{
    $payments = Payment::findOrFail($id);

    $filename = $payments->file_name;
    $foldername = storage_path('app/public/loonstrookjes');
    $pathToFile= '/'. $foldername . '/' . $payments->filename;
    $pdf = PDF::loadFile($pathToFile)->stream($filename . '.pdf');
    dd($pdf);

    $file_url = Storage::url('app/public/' . $payments->file_name);

    return view('paychecks.details', compact('payments', 'file_url', 'pdf'));
}
```

This is the function I'm trying to use right now, which is giving the "forbidden" error. Eventhough last time I checked the dd does show the right file path and name.

The ideal image would be a password having to be filled in before the PDF gets shown, but until then it would be great to get the PDF to show in general.

Please I hope anybody will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it will display the document first

```
    $payment= Payment::find($id);
    return response()->file(public_path().'/documentfolder/'.$payment->file_name);
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't have the PDFs in a public directory since I only want the person that it belongs to to be able to view it.